# Preventing document from being printed

Tags: packages, printing

Banknotes (money) have printing-preventive patterns in them, like e.g. the [EURion constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation). This prevents the note from being scanned and copied and printed (since most printers and scanners are programmed to recognise them). The notes probably also have many other measures for preventing these things.

My question is: is there a LaTeX package that exploits e.g. this anti-money-printing functionality, so that it could be added it to a document?

I tried to look around a bit on CTAN, but couldn't find any.

Note: Of course finding something *perfectly* safe would be close to impossible.

Comment: I don’t know whether this approach interest you, but if you encrypt your documents with `pdftk` or `qpdf`, you can choose whether to allow printing. But it would surprise me if all PDF readers respected the restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read a PDF on screen but prevent it from being printed? Sorry, but as far as I know (ok, limited enough), not possible. You can fool some people by using Javascript in the PDF to display the text, but make something entirely different being printed. You can produce a PDF with a second, invisible layer, which makes it difficult to copy and paste.

Even today you can buy a dot matrix printer for small money, which will print anything. And I don't think that the loads of cheapish inkjet printers from china have any kind of software running which checks the printout for dollas, euros or pounds.

And even if you could forbid printing, people can take screenshots and run some OCR software over them to recover your text in a new file.

Comment: I’m not really interested in finding something perfectly safe, since as both your answer and my question says, is fairly impossible. This is most for my own educational purposes. I like the JavaScript approach!